# XSD - XML string as value

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this .xsd file

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="request">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="fileName"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="configuration"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I can pass a XML with a XML string as value.

```
<request><fileName>kek.xml</fileName><configuration>"<xmlstring>some value</xmlstring>"</configuration></request>
```

But the XSD is giving me the following error:

Element 'configuration' is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children].

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Use CDATA:

```
<request>
  <fileName>kek.xml</fileName>
  <configuration><![CDATA[<xmlstring>some value</xmlstring>]]></configuration>
</request>
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_cdata_sections.htm